# Docker unable to access port outside the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running zookeeper( not thru docker ) on my localhost with port 2181.

Also, trying to run a docker image thru docker compose as follows.

```
#
  # Mesos
  #
  mesos-master:
    image: mesosphere/mesos-master:1.0.3
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - ~/mesos-data/master:/tmp/mesos
    environment:
      MESOS_CLUSTER: "mesos-cluster"
      MESOS_QUORUM: "1"
      MESOS_ZK: "zk://localhost:2181/mesos"
      MESOS_PORT: 5000
      MESOS_REGISTRY_FETCH_TIMEOUT: "2mins"
      MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT: "2mins"
      MESOS_LOGGING_LEVEL: INFO
      MESOS_INITIALIZE_DRIVER_LOGGING: "false"
```

Zookeepr is listening on port 2181, but still my docker process is unable to connect to the zookeeper port 2181.

Is there anything missing?

Thanks

Comment: try adding `hostname: 127.0.0.1` inside the compose file.

Comment: Is zk also running with `network_mode: host` ? Also instead of `localhost` try using `127.0.0.1`

Comment: ZK is a normal process and not running a as a docker.

Answer (score 11):

You are pointing to `localhost` from inside your docker container. This means that your docker container tries to connect to the container itself (localhost) on that specific port and NOT on the localhost of your server. You'll need to specify a specific IP to connect or you can run your docker container with the `--net="host"` option.

```
$ docker run -d --net="host" ...
```

This will create your container inside the host network and not inside the default bridge network.

Example:
I create a apache container (default) and map port on `127.0.0.1:80` of the host. So on my server I can curl `127.0.0.1:80`.

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 httpd
```

`curl 127.0.0.1:80` from host works:

```
$ curl localhost:80
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

If I start a help container with curl installed in which I will curl `127.0.0.1:80`:

```
    $ docker run --rm tutum/curl /bin/bash -c 'curl 127.0.0.1:80'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

Connection is refused because the container is inside the default bridge network and tries to curl itself on port 80.

Now I start the container inside the `host` network:

```
$ docker run --net=host --rm tutum/curl /bin/bash -c 'curl 127.0.0.1:80'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    45  100    45    0     0   8573      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22500
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

The `--net=host` translated to your docker-compose file means you have to add `network_mode: host`

Comment: I have added network_mode: host in my docker compose. Also, ZK is a normal process and not running a as a docker.

Comment: @user1578872 can you curl from your server to localhost:2181 to check if zookeeper is accessible and working fine? After that try the same from inside your container which is deployed on the host network.

Comment: It works in my host but not inside the container which is deployed in the host network. Not sure what else to be added.

Comment: curl 127.0.0.1:2181 instead of localhost didn't work too?

Comment: what is the output of docker `inspect container-id`? Check the Networks section. It should be empty for "Bridge": "", and there should be configuration for  "host": {} section

Comment: I also found something where they were adding `MESOS_IP=127.0.0.1` adn `MESOS_HOSTNAME=localhost` too as environment variables. + you are using docker, not toolbox, docker-machine or something.

Comment: curl 127.0.0.1:2181 also not working. But curl localhost:port works for other docker process running on the same host. docker inspect <container-id> results are as expecetd. bBridge is empty and host has json values.

Comment: MESOS_IP : 127.0.0.1
      MESOS_HOSTNAME : localhost also not helping here.

Comment: Thank you!!. I was having an issue with a Jenkins Agent that was a docker container and i am running docker agents within them to deal with the tools i need. I could not figure out why i could not curl to my registries. I now figured out that it was indeed this issue. Thanks!